# Active Directory 2008 multiple local user accounts

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I have installed a new Active Directory 2008 Domain controller into my environment. We are currently running the 2008 AD server as a secondary. The primary AD server is a 2003 Domain Controller. We are working on phasing this server out as soon as everything is off of it and new AD is working correctly.

We have been running the new 2008 AD server for about 2 months without any issues. Today I am working on a backup problem that occurred and I have found in the local user accounts (ctrl panel, user accounts) for the server that there are around 100 domain user accounts listed there. My question is this normal for an 2008 AD Domain controller to put local user accounts here.

I tried to remove a couple of these accounts and the user accounts just lock's to not responding. I have to close user accounts with task manager to get the user account to close. However if I open user accounts back up the user is gone.

So basically needing to know if this is correct behavior for an 2008 AD Domain controller to place domain user accounts in the local user account? Just trying to figure out if this is a problem or not?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of these user accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal. There are no local user accounts on a Windows DC. If you are in **User Accounts** and you click **Manage User Accounts** you do get a list of accounts. If you look at the middle column of the list you will see that the column header says **Domain** and the entries in that column should all be the name of the Windows domain that the DC is a controller for. If you manage to remove an account from this list I suspect you are actually removing a domain account. You should instead use **Active Directory Users and Computers** to manage domain accounts. Really the entire **User Accounts** applet should be removed from the Control Panel when a server has the DC role added to it, but I guess Microsoft didn't feel that was necessary.